# Downsize an Image without using loops

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have an Image, that I would like to resize it, so it will contain 1/4 #pixels.

By picking the odd x pixels, then the odd y pixels.

It is easy to be done with loops, this way:

```
[x, y] = size(Image);
DownSizedImage = ones(x/2);

for i=1:2:x
    for j=1:2:y
        DownSizedImage(ceil(i/2),ceil(j/2)) = Image(i,j);
    end
end
```

For an example this matrix 4X4

```
Mat = [1, 1, 4, 4;
       7, 5, 1, 3;
       9, 2, 1, 0;
       0, 0, 5, 4;]

DSI = [1 4;
       9 1;]
```

Any idea how could I do that without loops ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DownSizedImage = Image(1:2:x,1:2:y);`

Comment: @JensBoldsen That should be an answer.

Comment: Or `Image(1:2:end,1:2:end);`. That avoids the `size` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use:

```
DownSizedImage = Image(1:2:end,1:2:end);
```